# How do neural networks learn specific features throughout the layers?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, representation-learning

I was reading about convolutional neural networks and I came across such an explanation:

> Consider detecting features in human face. The earlier layers of neural networks learn coarse features such as edges in the images and the latent layers learn more complex ( finer) features such as eyes, nose and etc

I am wondering why this is a true statement, namely how can we know that a neural network first starts by learning primitive features and then learns complex features. Could you please explain?

Comment: Where did you find that explanation? Can you provide the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that a layer can only learn a function based on it's inputs - that's clear. When you look at a convolutional neural network, each output pixel of an early layer only gets a very small fraction of the whole image as input. For example: If your first layer uses a `3 x 3` kernel, then each output only depends on only 9 pixels. Try detecting anything other then edges with that much information - it's not not possible. In other words: Looking at a 3 by 3 image you will be able to see an edge and its orientation, but not something like a nose.

In contrast, the later layers depend on a much larger portion of the image and can thus learn high-level features like a nose.

It's more a question of whats possible for the layers to learn and not a question of the network self-organizing it's resources.
And besides just reasoning like that you can visualize what the kernels in the individual layers respond to. I found [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/28272/are-these-visualisations-the-filters-of-the-convolution-layer-or-the-convolved-i) that also has an image with some further information on that.

**EDIT** *In response to the first comment:*

To further clarify how a CNN works, here is an example, where $X_0$ is the input image and $X_1$ is the output of the first CNN-Layer:

1. Each convolution in the first layer receives a small (e.g. `3 x 3`) area of pixels of $X_0$ and provides an output pixel. Here it is only possible to detect simple features (edges / gradients) because of the reason stated above.
2. The output of the first Layer $X_1$ is again an image, with the following properties:

   - A single pixel represents a `3 x 3` area in the original input
   - Effectively $X_1$ is a map that encodes the location of the simple features that got detected.
3. Because of the above properties, applying another `3 x 3` convolution to $X_1$ causes that

   - That convolution effectively depends on a `5 x 5` area of $X_0$, i.e. a `3 x 3` area of $X_1$
   - That convolution responds to certain arrangements of these 1st-level features, e.g. two adjacent edges with different orientations are a corner. You can think of the CNN-layers as a hierarchy where initial layers provide basic features the next layer detects compositions of these, the next layer detects compositions of the compositions and so on.

> is it like the many basic functions (like the edge detections ) are added together and then create a function that fires high values when a "nose" detected ?

So yes, you can say it like this. This is exactly where the thought of hierarchy fits in.

Comment: So what you are saying is as layers progress the function learned become more and more complex in terms of number of input pixels , which can be regarded as capturing more complex features such as nose right ? The only thing that I did not understand how the coarser features are related to the high level features in the network , is it like the many  basic functions (like the edge detections ) are added together and then create a function that fires high values when a "nose" detected ?

Comment: Yes, you can say that - I extended the answer to clarify this a bit more